# xCode 6.0.1 valid architecture issue;GTLFramework

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api, ios8, xcode6

I am using googleDriveSDK in my app and it was compiling fine for xCode 5.1. The build settings were:

`architecture : armv7 and armv7s`

`valid architecture : armv7 , armv7s,armv 64.`

But in xCode 6.0.1, the build is giving linker error. It says GTL framework is not available for armv 7s/64. so i had to change the settings for xCode 6 as

`architecture  armv7`
 and `valid architecture : armv7 , armv7s,armv 64.`

it runs fine now. I have tested it on 5,5s,5c version well .But I wonder What happens if in build settings, I keep ARCHS armv7 and VALID ARCHS armv7 armv7s armv64? I am confused between what archs and valid archs is all about.

Am i missing on something?